# Inline update to a custom react-select styles object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

We have a custom style for a select widget built using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home), called `darkSelectStyles`, which is used like this:

```
<Select
    isMulti
    styles={darkSelectStyles}
    value={ourValuesArray}
    onChange={ourHandlerFunction}
    options={ourSelectOptions}
/>
```

`darkSelectStyles` is an object of functions, where each function returns the styles for a specific part of the select, and we'd like to make an inline update to the styles for the `control` part of the select. Something like:

```
const updatedStyles = {
    ...darkSelectStyles,
    control: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        minWidth: '300px'
    })   
}
```

However this completely replaces what we had previously for the `control` styling function... This is what our `darkSelectStyles` object looks like (note it already has 7-8 styles on `control`, which are lost in the above example):

```
export const darkSelectStyles = {
    container: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        display: 'inline-block'
    }),
    control: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        minHeight: '5px',
        fontSize: '1.05em',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        borderRadius: 5,
        border: 'none',
        backgroundColor: state.isDisabled ? 'rgba(167, 0, 0, 0.45)' : null,
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE'
        }
    }),
    option: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        padding: '2px 6px 3px 6px',
        fontSize: '0.95em',
        marginTop: 0
    }),
    menu: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        border: '1px solid #222222',
        boxShadow: cbbBoxShadow,
        zIndex: 999
    }),
    menuList: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        color: '#222222'
    }),
    singleValue: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        maxWidth: 'none',
        position: 'static',
        transform: 'none',

        // left: 0,
        color: state.isDisabled ? 'white' : '#222222',
        fontWeight: 700,
        overflow: 'initial'
    }),
    valueContainer: (provided) => ({ 
        ...provided, paddingBottom: 
        '0px', 
        paddingRight: '0px' 
    }),
    input: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        color: '#EEEEEE' 
    }),
    indicatorSeparator: () => ({ display: 'none' }),
    dropdownIndicator: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        padding: '0px 6px 0 2px',
        color: state.isDisabled ? 'white' : '#222222'
    })
};
```

How can I fix the `updatedStyles` function to handle the new width without losing the other styles?

### Edit

We could change `darkSelectStyles` into a function that takes parameters (minWidth) and returns an object with all of the functions, however this approach could become quite messy if a lot of parameters are used to set styles for different parts of the select widget...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
const updatedStyles = {
    ...darkSelectStyles,
    control: (provided) => ({
        ...darkSelectStyles.control(provided, state), //assuming state is available
        minWidth: '300px'
    })   
}
```

This invokes the original `control` function from `darkSelectStyles` as part of the return in your updated `control` function, and then updates the `minWidth` also.